# Get consumer group state using confluent kafka python

Tags: python, apache-kafka, confluent-kafka-python

I am doing this way currently to get the `groupmetadata` for list of consumers

```
    admin = AdminClient({ 'bootstrap.servers' : config['kafka']['brokers']  })
for group in config['kafka']['groups']:
    metadata = admin.list_groups(group)
    print(metadata[0].state)
```

Is there a way to achieve the below

```
metadata = admin.list_groups(config['kafka']['groups']) //list of groups
```

It throws an error that it expects only one string argument, the next one is an integer.

But when I checked the [doc](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/clients/confluent-kafka-python/html/index.html#confluent_kafka.admin.AdminClient.list_groups), [this](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/clients/confluent-kafka-python/html/_modules/confluent_kafka/admin.html#AdminClient.list_groups), I expect that it would work for selected groups.

What am I missing here? is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docs say `group` param is only `str`, not `list(str)`

If you don't provide it, it will return **all** groups, which you could then choose to filter, based on your config.

Comment: Yes, I agree. But the cluster has 400+ groups whereas I need to filter groups but not more than 30. Is there a way? like describe groups in kafka-python?

Comment: Not that I know of. The API that you found is the only way. Your original loop seems like the only way to do what you want, then